# Height in percentage isn't working, works in pixels

Tags: html, css

For some reason my `div`s aren't gaining height when I apply `.section {height: 100%;}`, but when I give it a `height` attribute in pixels it works. The idea is that I want the `div`s to use the browsers window, so the `div` would cover entire section of the browser no matter what the resolution of the display.

http://jsfiddle.net/marrto/npe2y/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> 10 </title>
<!-- Slidebars CSS -->

<link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" >
</head>
<body>

<!-- MAIN AREA -->


<!-- WRAPPER - WRAPPS NAVIGATION AND LOGO-->
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"> 
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"> <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo"> </a>
        </div>

        <div class="navBar">
        <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#topbar">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- WRAPPER END -->





<div id="topbar" class="section">
<div class="content">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</div>

<div id="about" class="section">
<div class="content">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</div>

<div id="photos" class="section">
<div class="content">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</div>

<div id="contact" class="section">
<div class="content">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</div>


<!-- WRAPPER - WRAPPS NAVIGATION AND LOGO-->
<div id="container">
    <div id="footer"> 
        <div class="legal">
            text
        </div>

        <div class="site">
            Text
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- WRAPPER END -->



    </body>
</html>


body { /* general font size, family and color */
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #343434;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.sb-toggle-left {
    display: none;
}

#wrapper { /* wrapps logo and the navigation links */
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 3px 0 #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #ccc;
    box-shadow:         0 0 3px 0 #ccc; 
}

.section:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #b1d994;
}
.section:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #5bc473;
}

.section {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5%;
}


.content {
    width: 60%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: justify;
}

/*
#topbar {
    background-image: url('banner.jpg');
}
*/

#header {
    width: 60%;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-width: 600px;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    padding-top: .9em;  
}

.navBar {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 1.3em;
}

.navBar ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.navBar li {
float:left;
}

.navBar a:link, .navBar a:visited {
    display: block;
    color:#4a4949;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}


.navBar a:hover {
    color:#ababab;
} 

#container { /* wrapps logo and the navigation links */
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 3px 0 #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #ccc;
    box-shadow:         0 0 3px 0 #ccc; 
}


#footer {
    width: 60%;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.legal {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 1.3em; 
}

.site {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 1.3em;
}
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dpnzv7jvidbytz8/AACJbMKi07DO7Ezatli3ZOfUa
full site

Comment: In the dropbox link i have the full website. and i noticed when i remove the doctype, it changes to what i wanted to achieve all along. But don't we need doctype?

Answer (score 4):

If the parent element doesn't have height set explicitly, % height won't work in it's children...

in your case the parent of divs having class `section` is `<body>`, which doesn't have a height set.

Answer (score 3):

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/npe2y/2/) a wirking fiddle. 
I just changed 100% with 100vh

```
.section {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 5%;
}
```

Comment: **[Browser support for `vh`](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)** is far from outstanding.

Comment: _Close_ ;-) Supported in most modern browsers. Buggy in iOS7, but probably (hopefully) not for long.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set following css:

```
html,body{
height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using js

```
element = document.getElementsByClassName("section");
   for(element in ele){
    ele.style.width=screen.width+"px";  
   }
```

if width is gonna fixed the height won't change

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by setting position: absolute in the very top level container div.